# Total number of longtables (v3.02+)

Tags: tables, numbering, longtable, counters

I'm wondering, are there any ways to get (and forward-reference at the beginning of the document) the total number of tables when using longtables? There are utility packages for standard table counter, but it's not used in [longtable](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf) anymore starting from v3.02:

> Counter for the tables, added in V3.02. Previous versions just used
>   the LaTeX counter table, but this fails if table is reset during a
>   document, eg report class resets it every chapter. This was changed
>   from \newcount\LT@tables in V3.04. LaTeX counters are preserved
>   correctly when \includeonly is used. In the rest of the file
>   \LT@tables has been replaced by \c@LT@tables without further comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\makeatletter 
\gdef\LTno{??}
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\write\@auxout{\gdef\string\LTno{\theLT@tables}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

There are \LTno\ longtables here.

\begin{longtable}{c}a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\\end{longtable}

zzz

\begin{longtable}{c}a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\\end{longtable}

zzz

\begin{longtable}{c}a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\\end{longtable}

zzz

\end{document}
```